# On change select, if item has the same value in dropdown check the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a dynamic dropdown list out of checkboxes. What I want is when the dropdown changes (on select) I want it to check the checkboxes with the same values or perhaps with the same `name`? I also want it to do vice versa, if you `check` a checkbox the select dropdown should change as well.

Here is my codepen - http://codepen.io/BryanBarrera/pen/QEXVxY

I am having issues writing this. Here is what I have. What is the best approach for this? How do I match up elements to change or check the `checkboxes`?

Any idea or suggestions would be much apprecated

```
"use strict";

var checkBoxes = $('.form-item'),
    checkBox = $('input[type="checkbox"]'),
    $select = $('<select></select>').appendTo('body').wrap('<div class="select-dropdown"></div>');

checkBoxes.each(function (n) {
    var dataText = $(this).find('label').text();
    var dataValue = $(this).find('input').val();
    $select.append('<option value="' + dataValue + '">' + dataText + '</option>');
});


$select.on('change', function(){

  var checkboxvalue =  $(this).val();

  var a =  $(this).filter(function(){return this.value=='checkboxvalue'});

  console.log(a);
  console.log(checkboxvalue);

  if (checkboxvalue == $(this).val() ) {
   // alert('yup');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
$select.on('change', function(){

  var checkboxvalue =  $(this).val();
  $('input[value='+checkboxvalue+']').prop('checked', true);

});

checkBox.on('change', function(){

  var selectValue =  $(this).val();
  $select.val(selectValue)

});
```

You probably want some other function to handle multiple selection, because you dropdown obviosly don't support multiple selection like checkboxes.

---

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/akmf8gep/)**

Comment: ahh man didn't think of that, but this does it.  I'm going to compare what you did to my code to see what I did wrong. Thanks! @empiric

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value of the checkbox element, but not actually checking the box. You also need to do this:

```
$('#checkbox-selector').prop('checked', true);
```